# Ruby background TCP Server

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpserver

I wish to create a TCPServer which listens in the background while the script continues it's normal execution.
For example-

```
server=TCPServer.open(srvhost,srvport)
    client=server.accept 
    res=send_request_cgi({
        'uri' => "/",
        'method' => 'GET',
        'vars_get' => 
            'cmd' => rand_text_alphanumeric(10)
        }
    })
    print "#{res.headers}" 
    data=client.recv(1024)
    puts data
    client.close
```

This pauses the script at the listener.

Objective-The server will always receive a response on srvport which it should print.

Edit-

```
webserv=Thread.new do
        server=TCPServer.new(srvhost,srvport)
        client=server.accept 
        data=client.recv(1024)
        if(data.empty?)
                puts 'nope'
                client.close
                server.close
                webserv.exit
        end
        puts data
        client.write(cmd)
        client.close
        server.close
        webserv.exit
        end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your server in a new [Thread](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html#method-c-new) with

```
websrv = Thread.new do
  <your server logic> # Main server loop, handle data, etc.
ensure
  <your cleanup code> # Close connections, files, etc.
end
<application code>
websrv.join # wait for web server to do its thing
```

Needless to say, in ruby you'd usually wrap that in some sort of BackgroundServer class, but the basic idea is the same.

Note that rubys *threads* don't really execute in parallel; the interpreter just takes care of switching back and forth between them.

Comment: however,once I run the program again I get a address already in use error,even though I added a client.close in the do block.Any workaround?

Comment: Depends. My guess is that the `client.close` isn't reached. Did you terminate the program early? (like by pressing Ctrl+C or from the main thread)

Comment: If you need a way to send some sort of close signal to the thread, you could use a [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html). Closing with Ctrl+C is handled as a normal exception in ruby, so you can just rescue that in your main thread and send a close signal to your background server before raising the exception further up.

Comment: @ShakshamJaiswal I did some testing; you can add an `ensure` block to the thread and it *should* always run, even if you kill the thread, so you can put your `client.close` there.
EDIT: Updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: No I never terminate i.normally the program closes after reaching exit but the server still runs.

Comment: I've made an edit to question,can you look at it?
It works when the data is received however server still continues running if no data is received,or if you suggest how to add a timeout scheme there? Like listen only for 10 seconds and then close if no data is received.That would be really helpful.

Comment: The problem might be that the main program reaches its end after spawning the thread. At that point it probably just closes the thread and ends. Try adding `websrv.join` at the end, which instructs the main thread to wait until the `websrv` has finished before continuing. But again, ensure should also work to, well, *ensure* that the connection is closed either way.